# Object 'world' not found

Tags: r

I am just trying the following code from online to draw a map on my study area but it is giving the following error even despite using the online code as it is:

```
**install.packages(c("cowplot","googleway", "ggplot2", "ggrepel",
                   "ggspatial", "libwgeom", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata"))                 
library("ggplot2")  
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)**
```

Error in st_as_sfc.SpatialPolygons(sp::geometry(x), ...) :
package rgeos required for finding out which hole belongs to which exterior ring

> class(world)
> Error: object 'world' not found

I have no idea what's causing this error as I am new in R.
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Install the `rgeos` package as well. That's what the first error is telling you.

Comment: @MrFlick You are absolutely right. Including the rgeos in the package solved the problem. Appreciate your response. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you just need to install rgeos package and load it

```
install.packages(c("cowplot","googleway", "ggplot2", "ggrepel",
               "ggspatial", "libwgeom", "sf", "rnaturalearth", "rnaturalearthdata", 
"rgeos"))                 
library("ggplot2")  
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library(rgeos)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)
```

**